# Выбор MySQL или SQLite высоконагруженного проекта

Tags: highload, sqlite, php, mysql

Здравствуйте!

Подскажите, какую БД лучше выбрать(MySQL или SQLite) для высоконагруженного проекта на PHP. Записей в таблице около 50. Обновление данных в них каждый час. Количество заходов может доходить до 50к в день.

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: точно не лайт))

Comment: Если честно то невозможно ответить, потому что вопрос не полный.

Какой объем будет у самих таблиц? (50 мб , 50 гб, 50 тб)

Какие виды запросов осуществляются к базе? 

Только where id=...   или требуется поиск, проходы по всей таблице?

требуется ли возвращать большой объем данных(хорошая ли пропускная способность между сервером БД и приложением)?

Comment: Если выбирать между MySQL и SQLite, то однозначно MySQL, вообще, на вскидку, если я правильно понял, лучше всего использовать key/value db типа редиски

Comment: @andy87, странно, что Вы считаете проект с приведенными характеристиками *высоконагруженным*. 

Выбор надо делать исходя из того, что SQLite это по сути *однопользовательская* база. 

Т.е. если в Вашем проекте **одновременно** модифицировать базу могут *несколько* приложений (независимых процессов), то надо брать MySQL.

Answer (score 3):

Начинать нужно с mysql и далее смотреть по обстановке. Расширять вы можете в глубь или в ширину для подъема производительности.

Расширение в глубь - прикрутить в приложение кеширующий механизм, читать из которого возможно гораздо быстрее.

Расширение в ширину - добавить еще один mysql-сервер. Производительность увеличится чуть меньше чем в 2 раза.

Хотя с другой стороны 50 килозапросов в день = 35 в минуту = чуть меньше, чем 1 запрос в 2 сек. mysql будет вполне справляться, это не нагрузка для одного таблицы в 50 записей. Единственное, что наврятле они будут идти равномерно. )

В общем порядок действий такой: Ставим -> Тестим -> Изменяем/Добавляем -> Тестим -> Изменяем/Добавляем -> Тестим -> Изменяем/Добавляем -> Тестим -> Изменяем/Добавляем -> Тестим......... и так далее..

Answer (score 2):

MySQL + я бы посоветовал работу с базой через pdo только ради транзакций. Для высоконагруженных проектов без транзакций некуда.

Comment: Вы что-то путаете, транзакции, наверное, самое главное зло в вопросе горизонтальной расширяемости

Comment: AlexWindHope, я за стабильность.

Answer (score 1):

Я использовал бы  MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

Недавно проводили сравнение Mysql с mariadb. Mariadb хорошо себя показала. А если между Mysql и SQLite то естественно Mysql.)